# How to Post to a specif users wall - using graph API

Tags: facebook

I have successfully posted a message to my own feed (logged in users).. now am trying to post to a specif friends wall... but no luck so far..

I tried putting the parameter "to" with the target users ID but the post is still happening in my news feed and can see by all others..

Please help
Anz

Comment: What response are you getting? Any errors in there? (also, "Most write operations require extended permissions for the active user." Do you have them? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing )

Comment: I have the publish_stream permisson.. but still the post to specific wall is not working.. also from facebook forums I understand that the Graph API doesnot support action_ links so I decided to use the old REST API for this purpose and its working.. 

One prob I still have is with REST API stream.publish I tried to post to multiple friends using comma seperated target_id but its posting to the first friends wall only.. any idea why its behaving like this? If its a usual behavior my only solution is to call stream.publish for each friend..

Answer (score 0):

It's all in [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing)

> Most write operations require extended
>   permissions for the active user. See
>   the authentication guide for details
>   on how you can request extended
>   permissions from the user during the
>   authentication step.

`/PROFILE_ID/feed`  write to the given profile's feed/wall

Comment: Thanks for the link.. ok I think it will solve my prob but from the facebook forums http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=222559#p222559 I got the action_links not supported with graph api so I decided to use stream.publish.. can you please help me out with the prob I commented above..